# error opening security policy file /etc/X11/xserver/SecurityPolicy

Tags: 16.04, security, remote-desktop, vnc

I am trying to connect to VNCserver hosted on an Ubuntu. I am using a Mac. terminal to connect via the command `open vnc://username@IP`. The log files throw me an error on the security policy file. I can't see any such file though. I've tried solutions on the Internet but don't work.

```
Xvnc Free Edition 4.1.1 - built Feb 25 2015 23:02:21
Copyright (C) 2002-2005 RealVNC Ltd.
See http://www.realvnc.com for information on VNC.
Underlying X server release 40300000, The XFree86 Project, Inc


Sat May 27 13:50:32 2017
 vncext:      VNC extension running!
 vncext:      Listening for VNC connections on port 5901
 vncext:      created VNC server for screen 0
error opening security policy file /etc/X11/xserver/SecurityPolicy
Could not init font path element /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/Type1/, removing from list!
Could not init font path element /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/Speedo/, removing from list!
Could not init font path element /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/misc/, removing from list!
Could not init font path element /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/75dpi/, removing from list!
Could not init font path element /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/100dpi/, removing from list!
Could not init font path element /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/, removing from list!
Could not init font path element /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/, removing from list!
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast

** (gnome-session-binary:1804): WARNING **: Unknown option -session=gnome-classic
Failed to parse arguments: Unknown option --login
Window manager warning: Log level 32: could not find XKB extension.
Window manager warning: Missing composite extension required for compositing

Sat May 27 13:51:25 2017
 Connections: accepted: 0.0.0.0::56680

Sat May 27 13:51:26 2017
 SConnection: Client needs protocol version 3.3

Sat May 27 13:51:29 2017
 Connections: closed: 0.0.0.0::56680 (Clean disconnection)
 Connections: accepted: 0.0.0.0::56681

Sat May 27 13:51:30 2017
 SConnection: Client needs protocol version 3.3
 SConnection: AuthFailureException: Authentication failure
 Connections: closed: 0.0.0.0::56681 (Authentication failure)

Sat May 27 13:51:36 2017
 Connections: accepted: 0.0.0.0::56682
 SConnection: Client needs protocol version 3.3
 SConnection: AuthFailureException: Authentication failure
 Connections: closed: 0.0.0.0::56682 (Authentication failure)

Sat May 27 13:51:39 2017
 Connections: accepted: 0.0.0.0::56683

Sat May 27 13:51:40 2017
 SConnection: Client needs protocol version 3.3
 SConnection: AuthFailureException: Authentication failure
 Connections: closed: 0.0.0.0::56683 (Authentication failure)
```

My `~/.vnc/xstartup` file contents are as below. Note - I've tried without the `gnome-classic` line too.

```
#!/bin/sh

# Uncomment the following two lines for normal desktop:
unset SESSION_MANAGER
# exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc

gnome-session -session=gnome-classic &
[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &
x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
x-window-manager &
```

Command used to start my VNC server : `vncserver`

```
xauth: (stdin):1:  bad display name "dexter:1" in "add" command

New 'dexter:1 (dexter)' desktop is dexter:1

Starting applications specified in /home/dexter/.vnc/xstartup
Log file is /home/dexter/.vnc/dexter:1.log
```

Details of Ubuntu via `lsb_release -a` command

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

Supported sessions via `ls /usr/share/xsessions` command

```
gnome.desktop                   gnome-flashback-metacity.desktop
gnome-flashback-compiz.desktop  ubuntu.desktop
```

I access my remote machine with `ssh username@IP`. I have also tried using the `-X` and `-Y` options.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu is running on the remote machine? what available sessions does it support (`ls /usr/share/xsessions`)? How are you starting the vncserver (what command line options etc.)?

Comment: Hey @steeldriver I have updated my post with all the details you asked for.